# Detectar desconexión de cliente Android en Socket.IO con NodeJS

Tags: android, nodejs, socket.io, real-time

estoy intentando hacer una aplicación en tiempo real con [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/), pero tengo problemas para detectar cuando un usuario se desconecta.

En Android puedo desconectarme manualmente con la siguiente función:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mSocket.disconnect();
}
```

El problema está cuando pierdo conexión con el servidor repentinamente, ya sea desconectándome de Internet, apagando el dispositivo, etc.

Tengo entendido que el funcionamiento de Socket.IO es mantener una conexión mínima entre cliente y servidor, similar a enviar un dato y esperar una respuesta cada cierto tiempo. Con esto asumo que el servidor debe detectar el momento en que se pierde la conexión con un cliente.

Gracias por sus ayudas.

Answer (score 1):

En la misma web que has linkeado tienes como detectar una desconexion [Ejemplo](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#event-disconnecting)

```
socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
  // ...
});
```

En `reason` obtienes el motivo de desconexion en un `String`, puedes hacer la funcion que quieras dentro del metodo de ejemplo.

Comment: Sí lo probé, pero no detecta la desconexión repentina. Lo que hace es decirme la razón de la desconexión. Lo que necesito es que detecte cuando pierdo conexión.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de mucho tiempo encontré la solución.
Sí detecta la conexión, pero es lento. Hay que modificar los intervalos de tiempo para hacer que dicha detección sea casi instantánea.

Hay una parte en la página de [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/) que dice:

> Among those options:
>
> pingTimeout (Number): how many ms without a pong packet to consider the connection closed (60000).
>
> pingInterval (Number): how many ms before sending a new ping packet (25000).

Modificando estos valores se puede acelerar el tiempo de respuesta entre la desconexión del cliente y la detección, de la misma, en el servidor.

Para hacerlo, se agrega una configuración previa en el `require()` de la siguiente forma:

```
const server = require('http').createServer();

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  path: '/test',
  serveClient: false,
  // below are engine.IO options
  pingInterval: 10000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
  cookie: false
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Con esto solo se modifican los valores y listo, pero siempre recordando que, de ponerle valores muy bajos, cualquier pequeño error de conexión puede interpretarse como una desconexión completa del cliente.
Yo lo probé con `3000` y me funcionó muy bien.